# If sensitivity list in VHDL is not synthesizable, why does it gives an error due the Analysis and Synthesis?

Tags: vhdl, intel, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

To provide sequential logic in design with VHDL I have to use process statement, which has `sensitivity_list`. From different sources I know, that sensitivity list is non-synthesizable construction, i.e., if I will synthesize this code:

```
    ...
    process(c)
    b <= a and c;
    end process;
    ...
```

I would not have any latch by `c` signal, it will just be a usual AND-gate. But, when I synthesize code without sensitivity list:

```
    ...
    process
    b <= a and c;
    end process;
    ...
```

no matter what version of VHDL I choose, I get the same problem:

> Error (10442): VHDL Process Statement error at process_test.vhd(79):
>   Process Statement must contain either a sensitivity list or a Wait
>   Statement

My question is: why does synthesizer care about sensitivity list? In my understanding, it is over-concerned about customers and this cannot be an error, but a critical warning, or even nothing, and warnings only when the simulation is on.

UPD. Here is full code and some images. I used Quartus Prime Standard 16.1

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    entity stck_ovflw is
        port 
        (
            a       : in std_logic;
            c       : in std_logic;
            b       : out std_logic
        );
    end entity;
    architecture rtl of stck_ovflw  is
    begin
        process(c)
        begin
            b <= a AND c;
        end process;
    end rtl;
```

RTL Synthesis:
[image]
Modelling:
[image]

Comment: VHDL 2008 allows the keyword `all` in the sensitivity list. This enormously simplifies things as you just need to take care about whether you have a `wait` statement in the process (then you can't have a sensitivity list at all) or not (then you just write `all` into it and don't care much otherwise).

Comment: The VHDL standard does not require a process contain a wait statement explicit or implied by a sensitivity list. Processes suspend and resume execution in wait statements. Simulation of other processes and the advancement of simulation time can't proceed with a process continually executing nor can synthesis results be verified. Flagging a process without a wait statement (explicit or implicit) is useful in determining synthesis eligibility.

Comment: @mfro, thank you for your comment! Yes, this keyword simplifies, but my question more about "why", not "how"

Comment: @user1155120, thank you for comment, I don't quite understand the last sentence. But from the first line - do you mean, that it is up to compiler - check wait statements/sensitivity list or not? Which synthesizer does not gives an error on a process without wait/sensitivity list?

Comment: I think the answer is simple here: you need to provide a sensitivity list simply because the language specification requires you to provide it. Point. If the question would have been: _why does VHDL have unnecessary (for synthesis) redundancy here?_ , we could go into a discussion and assumptions why this might be originally required (speed up simulation, etc.) but it wouldn't change the first answer. If it helps: there are lots of programming languages that contain unnecessary redundancies for mostly historic reasons. If you want to use such language, you have no choice but to accept that.

Comment: @mfro, exactly, my question is about "why", but a bit smaller: why does Altera's synthesizer tell an error, not a warning or critical warning. I know I have to admit it, as a rule, but I still hope to find some kind of explanation.

Comment: @mfro, I think my question is about this article: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/623933 ; but it is too old

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076.6--2004 (withdrawn) 6.4 Combinational logic "Any process that does not contain a clock edge or wait statement shall model either combinational logic or level-sensitive sequential logic."..."The process sensitivity list shall contain all signals read within the process statement." 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list "The process sensitivity list shall contain all signals read within the process statement." The withdrawn RTL synthesis standard required a sensitivity list for your process.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6--2004 (withdrawn) 5.1 Combinational verification
"To verify combinational logic, the input stimulus shall be applied first. Sufficient time shall be provided for the design to settle, and then the outputs examined.",,, Without the passage of simulation time synthesized logic can't be verified. -1996 says the same thing. There are synthesis tools that don't use VHDL for formal verification.

Comment: @user1155120 thanks a lot! That sounds like what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the job of a logic synthesiser to generate a circuit that behaves *exactly* the same as your RTL. A process without a sensitivity list or a wait if an infinite loop and so cannot be simulated. Therefore, given my first sentence, how can a logic synthesiser possibly generate a circuit that behaves exactly the same as your RTL?

This should never be a problem, because you should always simulate before you synthesise. So, you should have fixed this before the logic synthesiser ever sees your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to me as an explanation, it is just not beautiful) I mean - It sounds like protection from human mistakes, well, why not to go further and make an error about testbench absent? I mean, sensitivity_list/wait statements are only about simulation.

Comment: For addition - my example behaviour would be different between model and synthesized scheme: in Modelsim with the change of `a`  I would not see any changes like it is a latch; while on the RTL and then on the board there is clearly only AND-gate. So again, it would not generate me _exactly_ the same behaviour. The synthesis tools will give me a warning, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a little confused about the `sensitivity_list`. The `sensitivity_list` is a list of signals that trigger an activation of the `process`. Each time one of the signals in the `sensitivity_list` changes, the `process` is activated and the statements are evaluated.

In your example:

```vhdl
process(c) begin
    b <= a and c;
end process;
```

The process is activated only when `c` changes. This means that `b` takes a new value when `c` changes, but keeps the old value when `a` changes. This is not the behavior of a simple combinatorial AND gate and some sort of memory element will be needed for the synthesis to store the value of `b`.

In order to infer a simple AND gate, you must include all the input signals in the `sensitivity_list`. This can be done manually as:

```vhdl
process(a, c) begin
    b <= a and c;
end process;
```

Or in VHDL 2008 automatically with the keyword `all`:

```vhdl
process(all) begin
    b <= a and c;
end process;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand the aim of sensiivity_list, I just can't understand why does it necessary for synthesizer; my example would not be synthesized in a latch!

Comment: Your explanation works only for modelling: I can check it through the Modelsim. But on the RTL Viewer, I'll get usual AND-gate

Comment: You are right that Quartus ignore the sensitivity list while synthesizing, but I won't bet that all synthesis tools will always ignore the sensitivity list, some may infer a latch.

Comment: Agree, it needs to be tested on other synthesizers.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/623933 Looks like till 1997 no tool did it right